# How to delete asp.net profile property values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-profiles

I cerated a asp.net user profile with 1 property `List<string> Password` it contain 24 passwords , now i want to delete 4 passwords from this property values, how can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which 4 passwords do you need to delete? Top 4, bottom 4, middle 4 or what is the logic?

Comment: Any 4 from the list, i just want to know how we delete data from the profile properties?

Comment: You can use `Password.RemoveRange(index,count);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a range

```
Password.RemoveRange(index,count);
```

To remove a known index

```
Password.RemoveAt(index);
```

index is always zero based. [All list of methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4)